Pi4 python OpenCV timeout
I have been having some issues with getting a video stream from my cameras on my Pi4B. I am running this on Python. I have been getting the error;
VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): select() timeout

with the code;
import socket
import cv2
import numpy as np

print("OpenCV version:", cv2.__version__)
#print("CUDA support:", cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() > 0)

BUFF_SIZE = 65535
CHUNK_SIZE = 16384
WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 480
port = 5555
port2 = 5556

# Set the end marker
delimiter = b'FRAME_END_MARKER'

try:
    # Creat the UDP socket
    UDP_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    UDP_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, BUFF_SIZE)
    
    host_name = socket.gethostname()
    host_ip = "0.0.0.0"
    
    UDP_socket.bind((host_ip, port))
    print(f"UDP socket bound to {host_ip}:{port}")
    
    vid0 = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0', cv2.CAP_V4L2)
    #vid1 = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video2', cv2.CAP_V4L2)
    #vid0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    vid0.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'))
    
    while True:
        msg, client_addr = UDP_socket.recvfrom(BUFF_SIZE)
        print('Got UDP connection from ', client_addr)

        while(vid0.isOpened()):
            _, frame0 = vid0.read()
            #_, frame1 = vid1.read()
            
            frame = cv2.resize(frame0, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
            #frame1 = cv2.resize(frame1, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
            #frame = np.hstack((frame0, frame1))
            
            _, encoded_frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            
            # Split the encoded frame into chunks
            for i in range(0, len(encoded_frame), CHUNK_SIZE):
                chunk = encoded_frame[i:i + CHUNK_SIZE].tobytes()
                UDP_socket.sendto(chunk, client_addr)

            # Send the end marker after the last chunk
            UDP_socket.sendto(delimiter, client_addr)

finally:
    print("There was an error in the main loop")
    vid0.release()
    #vid1.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    UDP_socket.close
    print("The sockets have been closed")

I've had the best luck using V4L2; no other APIs have worked. Here's a list of my devices (v4l2-ctl --list-devices);
bcm2835-codec-decode (platform:bcm2835-codec):
        /dev/video10
        /dev/video11
        /dev/video12
        /dev/video18
        /dev/video31
        /dev/media3

bcm2835-isp (platform:bcm2835-isp):
        /dev/video13
        /dev/video14
        /dev/video15
        /dev/video16
        /dev/video20
        /dev/video21
        /dev/video22
        /dev/video23
        /dev/media0
        /dev/media1

rpivid (platform:rpivid):
        /dev/video19
        /dev/media2

UVC Camera (32e4:8830): HD USB  (usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1):
        /dev/video0
        /dev/video1
        /dev/media4

USB2.0 PC CAMERA: USB2.0 PC CAM (usb-0000:01:00.0-1.2):
        /dev/video2
        /dev/video3
        /dev/media5

And the formats for video0 and video2 (v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video* --list-formats);
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Type: Video Capture

        [0]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
        [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)

ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Type: Video Capture

        [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)

Sometimes, I can get a camera to work a little before it stops working. I don't know why that is. Please let me know if you have any other ideas or things I could try. I bet it's something stupid and small I'm missing. I appreciate any and all help.
Cheers,
Dwayne Wallace
